# i have string containing html tags and i need to display that string in html page in web app2

Tags: html, python-2.7, webapp2

I have string like in main.py:
    `mystring="<ol><li>shiva</li><li>putra</li>"`

and i want this value to display to in index.html using python webapp2. i have called `{{mystring}}`
Now it is displaying as it is i.e: `<ol><li>shiva</li><li>putra</li>`

But I want output Like:

- shiva
- putra

How would i display this please help me.

Comment: I have found the way to do it . Just add `{{ mystring |safe}}`

Answer (score 2):

use safe keyword `{{ mystring |safe}}` it should work.